Is passing a server action in a useMutation from tanstack query a good approach?
so I created a server action which is working, but I'm just wondering if passing a server action in a useMutation from tanstack query a good approach?
this is my previous take on submitting form

  const processForm = (values: z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>) => {
    createPost(values);
    setSuccess("");
    setError("");

    startTransition(() => {
      submitForm(values).then((data) => {
        setError(data.error);
        setSuccess(data.success);
      });
    });

  };

Is it this a good approach to make to use it as useMutation? I want to lessen using useState for setting loading and error
This is my approach
  const { mutate: createPost, isPending: isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (values: Inputs) => await submitForm(values),
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      router.push("/");
      router.refresh();
    },
  });

 const processForm = (values: z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>) => {
    createPost(values);
    }


